# Python argparse: How to set "--version" "--help" confilct?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python command program, it has optional `--version` and `--help` argument.
I want to set them conflict each other. It means I cannot type `--help --version` at the same time.

When I type `./demo --version --help` 
it outputs the program's version infomation.
When I type `./demo --help --version` 
it outputs the program's help infomation.

**I think this is weird**，so I want to set then conflict each other.

I tried the `add_mutually_exclusive_group`, but it makes no sense.

My program likes below:

```
#!python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version',
                    version='%(prog)s 1.0', help="Show program's version number and exit.")
#parser.parse_args(['--version','--help'])
parser.parse_args(['--help','--version'])
```

Thanks very much！

Comment: Both `--help` and `--version` print their message, and then do a system exit.  So the first one acts, and rest of the arguments aren't even seen.  While you could put them both in a mutually exclusive group, it wouldn't change behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not weird at all. There is no right way of doing it.
Some GNU utilities take the first argument and some take the specific one.

For example:

- `find --version --help` - will display version and exit
- `find --help --version` - will display help and exit
- `grep --version --help` - will display version and exit
- `grep --help --version` - will display version and exit